# How to solve linear equations in R with rectangular matrix

Tags: r

please i'm trying to solve a 7x2 matrix problem in the form below using R- software:

```
A=array(c(5.54,0.96,1.59,2.07,0.73,10.64,8.28,1.41,3.77,3.11,3.74,2.93,8.29,3.33), c(7,2))
A
#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  5.54 1.41
#[2,]  0.96 3.77
#[3,]  1.59 3.11
#[4,]  2.07 3.74
#[5,]  0.73 2.93
#[6,] 10.64 8.29
#[7,]  8.28 3.33
b=c(80814.25,34334.75,47921.75,59514.25,26981.25,63010.25,46646.25)
b
#[1] 80814.25 34334.75 47921.75 59514.25 26981.25 63010.25 46646.25
solve (A,b)
Error in solve.default(A, b) : 'a' (7 x 2) must be square
A %*% solve (A,b)
Error in solve.default(A, b) : 'a' (7 x 2) must be square
```

What do you think I can do to solve the problem. I need solution to two variables, x1 and x2, in the 7x2 matrix as stated above.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you're using `solve` when it needs a square input.   In `?solve` it discusses how you can use `qr.solve` for non-square matrices.

```
qr.solve(A,b) 

         [,1]
[1,] 3741.208
[2,] 6552.174
```

You might want to check that this is correct for your purposes. There are other ways to solve these types of problems.  This might help you though.

Answer (score 1):

The `corpcor` package offers a `pseudoinverse` function for finding the inverse of a rectangular matrix:

```
library(corpcor)
pseudoinverse(A)
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]      [,6]
[1,]  0.06271597 -0.05067830 -0.02922597 -0.03265713 -0.03964039 0.0230086
[2,] -0.05845856  0.08551514  0.05661287  0.06532450  0.06674243 0.0391552
            [,7]
[1,]  0.07239133
[2,] -0.05420334

pseudoinverse(A) %*% b
         [,1]
[1,] 3741.208
[2,] 6552.174
```